# UFW firewall question: set deny do all outgoing and incoming as default but with "allow out on http and https" why can't I browse web?

Tags: linux, web, debian

I have been losing all day on this. I'm trying to secure my system using UFW as a firewall, I've set **all** the **default incoming and outgoing** connections to **deny**. 
But then I created **separate *"allow out rules"*** for **ports 80; 80/tcp; 80/udp for HTTP and 443; 443/tcp; 443/udp for HTTPS**

However I still can't browse the net through chromium. I can if I revert the default outgoing to allow but not when it's on deny even with the rules.

My question: Why can't I browse the net at this point ? 
Is there a priority given to the default compared to the individual rules (that would make no sense to me)? Thanks

Comment: Is it a stateful firewall? Remember that when accessing something on the internet, the website will need to send you back packets, if the firewall is not able to understand that the packets are the "answer" of your request, the firewall may be blocking it.

Comment: Based on this article it is stateful https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/what-is-a-firewall-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: @RicardoReimao so to browse internet I also have to allow 80 incoming and 443 incoming ?

Comment: No it is not required,but where is your dns server located?

Comment: No where it's the router that fetches dns I think. I didn't set a custom dns. I'm not running a server, just trying to secure the system from 1) outside attacks 2) outbound communications to call home in case a malware infects me or the system infecting other devices on the network.

Comment: If a malware infects the system, it will probably use http/https to call home.

Comment: @ThoriumBR ok but then if I set default outgoing to allow, how can I trust that any rule (including the ones affecting my local network traffic between local IPs) will work since it's not respecting my "allow outgoing 80" and "allow outgoing 443" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution thanks to another user on a different forum, and I'll answer my own question for reference. Comments above contain interesting information for future readers.

Basically **I also had to allow port 53 to allow for the DNS**. In case it helps anyone as well !